# Any idea why I can't get a specific environment variable to appear in my prompt?

Tags: linux, command-line, environment-variables, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I would like to list the name of my Python virtualenv in my ZSH prompt but I can't get it to work. It is listed as an environment variable (VIRTUAL_ENV). I've set up another script that properly returns just the basename of my virtual env (envTest) but trying to incorporate that into my prompt didn't work either.

Prompt config:

```
PROMPT="╭─${user_host} ${current_dir} [${VIRTUAL_ENV}] ${rvm_ruby} ${git_branch}
╰─%B${user_symbol}%b "
```

Console:

```
╭─user@server ~/Projects/virtualenvTest []
╰─$ echo $VIRTUAL_ENV

╭─user@server ~/Projects/virtualenvTest []
╰─$ source envTest/bin/activate
╭─user@server ~/Projects/virtualenvTest []
╰─$ echo $VIRTUAL_ENV
/home/user/Projects/virtualenvTest/envTest
```

I can get other environment variables to show up in my prompt (e.g. LANG).

Prompt config:

```
PROMPT="╭─${user_host} ${current_dir} [${LANG}] ${rvm_ruby} ${git_branch}
╰─%B${user_symbol}%b "
```

Console:

```
╭─user@server ~/Projects/virtualenvTest [en_US.UTF-8]
╰─$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are actually using double quotes when defining your `PROMPT` then all parameters in there are substituted on definition and not each time the prompt is printed. You can prevent this by quoting `$VIRTUAL_ENV` differently.

As putting the whole prompt inside single quotes to prevent substitution of `$VIRTUAL_ENV` probably will break the rest of the prompt, try quoting just the `$` by prepending a `\`, like this

```
PROMPT="╭─${user_host} ${current_dir} [\${VIRTUAL_ENV}] ${rvm_ruby} ${git_branch}
╰─%B${user_symbol}%b "
```

---

I suspect that the other parameters work because they are substituted with something that is then evaluated each time. For example, `${user_host}` is probably substituted with something that contains at least the prompt escapes `%n` and `%m` with an `@` in between.

`${LANG}` works because it is already contains the expected value when you set the prompt.

You can easily confirm this by running:

```
echo $PROMPT
```